# tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open when upgrade using brew

Tags: homebrew

When I am using this command to upgrade my macOS big sur:

```
brew upgrade
```

shows some package could not be opened log:

```
==> Installing dependencies for sphinx-doc: gdbm, sqlite and python@3.9
==> Installing sphinx-doc dependency: gdbm
==> Pouring gdbm-1.20.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/Users/dolphin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/1ba06466fa01d44d117c266b9618127cf798782c736869d87ccfc0bc7cd25f12--gdbm-1.20.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz'
Error: Failure while executing; `tar --extract --no-same-owner --file /Users/dolphin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/1ba06466fa01d44d117c266b9618127cf798782c736869d87ccfc0bc7cd25f12--gdbm-1.20.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz --directory /private/tmp/d20210715-82868-1ez91q9` exited with 1. Here's the output:
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/Users/dolphin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/1ba06466fa01d44d117c266b9618127cf798782c736869d87ccfc0bc7cd25f12--gdbm-1.20.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz'

(base)
```

I am using this command to check the file:

```
~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads ⌚ 16:53:27
$ ls 1ba06466fa01d44d117c266b9618127cf798782c736869d87ccfc0bc7cd25f12--gdbm-1.20.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz   ‹ruby-2.7.2›
ls: 1ba06466fa01d44d117c266b9618127cf798782c736869d87ccfc0bc7cd25f12--gdbm-1.20.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz: No such file or directory
(base)
```

could not found the file, what should I do to fix the problem? I have already tried run:

```
brew cleanup
```

still not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a mirror of Homebrew, do not use it anymore, or try other mirror.

In a temp way, bypass the mirror: `export HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN=''`

Try another mirror `export HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN=https://another.mirrors.domain/homebrew-bottles`

Or you can put it in your `~/.zprofile` to make it effective in a long way:

`echo 'export HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN=""' >> ~/.zprofile`

Because:

> Homebrew's binary packages were migrated to GitHub Packages: https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/package

> On May 1, 2021, the sunset will impact all existing Bintray users. Bintray users will be blocked and will no longer be able to use the Bintray service.

Refer to:

1. [Bintray shuts down #691](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/691)
2. [Into the Sunset on May 1st: Bintray, GoCenter, and ChartCenter](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/)